# Powershell - Invoke-SQLCmd: how to check results

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am creating a script that will execute tSQLt Unit tests on the Dev server before a deployment o QA can proceed - this is part of Continuous Integration...

here is my Powershell script:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$DatabaseName
, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$UserName
, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Password
```

)

```
$filelocation = "c:\jenkinsdrops"
$DatabaseServer = "Server\DEV"

Invoke-Sqlcmd `
-Query "EXEC tSQLt.RUNALL" `
-ServerInstance $DatabaseServer `
-Database $DatabaseName `
-U $UserName `
-Password $Password `
-Verbose 4>"$Filelocation\$DatabaseName tSQLt Report.txt"`
```

the output in the console is:

[image]

and the (verbose) results output to the text file are like this:
[image]

Before we trigger the next step we have to ensure that all the unit tests passed, so the word `Failure` cannot appear in the output results file, and the word `failed` cannot be in the console output.

How can I check for that, or is there a better, more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming from your console output and can't test it currently but a try-catch block could work.

```
try {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd ...
}
catch {
    # Output a error and exit script?
}
```

eventually you need to add a -ErrorAction Stop to the Invoke-Sqlcmd.

Comment: Well the thing is there is always a response, I need to check the response for the word "Failure"